# How to stop DataGridView from polluting my Designer file with column controls?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm sure you know the problem, as soon as a BindingSource is connected to a DataGridView the DataGridView generates columns for each Property found in the Type of the BindingSource's DataSource and adds that crap to the Form.Designer.cs file.

We only use run time generated columns, the clutter in the designer file is just waste of code, so how can we stop this "feature" of the DataGridView in WinForms?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If its in the designer file, nobody will ever read it. Do you really have performance problems caused by this?

Comment: Thing is, VS randomly reorders items in the designer file from time to time and merging is really annoying if hundreds of lines only move inside the file. Secondly we use 8 DataGridViews on one Form that each generate around 100 columns automatically, only 3-4 at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell it to not auto-generate columns.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx

Comment: Sorry, does not work actually. as soon as the BindingSource gets connected in the designer, the columns are generated and the designer file gets polluted.

Comment: What is the big deal really?  No one looks at the designer file anyway.  I think the columns are generated just for the designer.  You could always take it off the form and manually add the datagridview to the form.

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false